# How can I get my Android application to terminate properly?

Tags: android, terminate

I have an Android application that writes data to the SD card. I want to be able to see this data from my PC, when I connect via a USB cable. Unfortunately the application remains in the background when I quit it, and some system buffers do not get flushed properly (or at least I think that is what happens). As a result I cannot see the data properly, unless I manually force the application to stop. Then the data becomes visible on the PC, as if by magic.

I would like to have the program terminate automatically when I quit the main activity, or better still I would like to find some way to flush the system buffers. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is unclear to me: (How) Do you write to the SDCard while it is mounted via USB?

Comment: There is an SQLite database on the SD card, and I use the ODBC driver to write to that. The application also produces a number of small test files. Some rows in the database and some of the text files are not visible from the PC, until I stop the application.

Comment: I think there was a problem with my phone when I posted this. The issue cleared up when I reset it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you close your file? Best would be in onPause() probably.

Check the activity lifecycle in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

EDIT:

If you really feel you need to kill your process, you can use

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

or

```
System.exit(n)
```

Comment: Of course I close my files/databases, and I have read about the activity life cycle umpteen times. That is precisely my problem. I do not want my application to remain in the background, because some data is not being committed to the SD card. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can explicitely finish() your activity. But you don't really have any influence on how long your process may remain in memory. Unless you kill your own process, but I don't think that might be necessary.

Comment: The activity does finish. I have checked that it passes through my onDestroy method. But this is not enough. The application remains in the background, and some of my data does not get written to the SD card.

Comment: I do not see anything the system would do when your process it terminated - besides closing open files, sockets etc. But you did that, as you said.

Comment: I am guessing that Android uses some kind of global buffer for all active applications, including ones that are in the background. That would kind of make sense.

Comment: I don't think so - it is a fairly standard Linux system, besides some changes regarding device drivers, power management and memory management. It does have a read/write cache, though - which would not be influenced by process termination . But see my comment above please.

Comment: I tried both killProcess and System.exit. They were both good tries, but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt its a file flush issue, you may not be writing the data to the SD card properly. Getting your application to "exit" is as simple as calling finish() in their onStop or onPause, depending on when you'd like it to quit.

Without code, we can't help!

Comment: I think that it must be some kind buffer issue, because the missing data appears as soon as I force the application to stop. The code to write the data is quite straightforward, but it is fairly long. I could create a simpler application to illustrate my point, but I am hoping that someone can suggest an answer.

Comment: I should point out that the missing data can be seen by other Android apps, and the same problem arises with both flat files and an SQLite database.